# Juntar 2 archivos CSV para poder generar consultas con Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, datetime

Quería consultar sobre cómo podría fusionar 2 archivos csv para poder generar consultas. Cabe destacar que no tengo permitido usar la libreria "pandas".

A modo de ejemplo tengo estos 2 csv:

**datos.csv:**

```
cod_pers,cod_enti,fec_venc
2317422,208,12/04/2022
1024726942,209,08/04/2022
2392115,210,02/04/2022
2086638,211,31/03/2022
2086638,212,13/03/2022
```

**enti.csv:**

```
cod_enti,cod_mercado
208,40
209,50
210,16
211,40
212,50
```

Y lo que busco es poder juntarlos mediante `cod_enti` y así poder evaluar la cantidad de `cod_pers` que tienen como `cod_mercado = 40` en los últimos 15 días.

Para ello tengo entendido que puedo generar la lectura de los archivos csv de la siguiente manera:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

#Leer el archivo CSV
str2date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
data_datos = np.genfromtxt('datos.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, converters={'fec_venc':str2date}, encoding="UTF-8")
data_enti = np.genfromtxt('enti.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, converters={'fec_venc':str2date}, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Y posteriormente poder realizar la búsqueda por días con un método simiar a este:

```
#definicion de dias
hoy = datetime.now()
ayer = hoy - timedelta(days=15)

#Generamos arreglo de fechas
valores_en_fecha =[]
calc_fech = data_datos['fec_venc']
for fec_obt in calc_fech:
    if (ayer <= fec_obt):
        valores_en_fecha.append(fec_obt)

tot_doc_mor_15d = len(valores_en_fecha)
print(tot_doc_mor_15d)
```

Pero para ello primero debo juntar los 2 archivos csv para poder generar la consulta.

Quedo atento a sus comentarios y cualquier tipo de ayuda, se agradece. Graciaaas!! :D

Comment: ¿Ambos archivos están ordenados por `cod_enti`?

Comment: No están ordenados, sólo se dio la coincidencia de que estén así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He agregado las siguientes lineas de código y me funciona perfecto la unión de los 2 CSV:

```
from numpy.lib import recfunctions

merged_data = recfunctions.join_by('cod_enti', data_datos, data_enti)
```